# SSMS 2008 adding ALTER TABLE WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT to my Procs

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, constraints, sql-server-2008

I have searched Google, BOL, and several forums and can't find the answer: 
I have a very small data base application that I write some queries and SPs to extract data. A few days ago I opened an exsiting SP to find that something had added code similar to that below, sometimes multiple lines referring to every table in the database. When I set up a new simple SP like "Select * from TinyTable" and re-open it, the same code has been inserted.

The last thing I remember doing was reviewing the settings for results to grid in SSMS 2008 R2. I'm afraid I may have accidently changed a setting but I've spent hours reviewing them and can't identify what it might be.

I have considered reinstalling SSMS to set back to defaults but I have a linked server set up to solve a collation conflict, and don't want to cause problems with that. If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it. I may be searching using the wrong terminology but can find nothing. As I say, I don't know for sure a change to the SSMS tools options is the problem but I suspect it could be something I have done.
Here's a sample of what gets automatically inserted at the bottom of every one of my procs:

```
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblLot]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblLot_tblLocation] FOREIGN         KEY([LocID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblLocation] ([LocID])
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely have *Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting > Object Scripting Options > Generate script for dependent objects* set to *True*.  Try changing the value to false.